# Issues With Exporting & Importing Oxygen Builder Site

Tags: plugins, migration

I'm not sure if anyone else has encountered this issue but when I try to move a site made with the oxygen builder, the shortcodes don't import properly and I have to manually copy and paste the shortcodes for each page in order for the site to display correctly.

Is there an easy way to automate this? I feel like I'm missing something. I'm using the free version of duplicator to move the site, not sure if I've missed an option I need to set or if this is just a problem with the oxygen builder plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Duplicator PRO *(ver 4.0.2)* to migrate Oxygen builder *(ver. 3.7.1)* created websites.

1. You have to switch to **advanced mode** in installer and in last step of migration **"search and replace"** old links to new links.
2. In Wordpress dashboard **Settings -> Permalinks**, scrool down and click **Save Changes**
3. **Oxygen -> Settings -> Security** click **Sign All Shortcodes**. Then check "I have made a complete backup of my site.", select the post types and click **"Start shortcodes singing process"**.
4. **Oxygen -> Settings -> CSS Cache** and click **Regenerate.**
5. Now  it's DONE! You can buy me a beer. :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

After migrating your site, you should do these steps to make it work:

1. Oxygen > Settings > Re-sign all Shortcodes
2. Oxygen > Settings > Regenerate CSS Cache
3. Wordpress > Settings > Permalinks : Save again

Without this you migrated site won‘t display correctly.